# AWSSDK Packages are not resolved in AEM 6.5

Tags: osgi, aws-sdk, aem, amazon-sqs, osgi-bundle

I am using AWSSDK to read messages from Amazon SQS, for that I have used software.amazon.awssdk maven group dependency with version 2.15.14, when there is no problem with build but OSGi bundles (Core) which is leveraging aws apis is in installed state at AEM Felix Console due to unresolved aws packages.

here is the list of packages which are not getting resolved.

```
software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials
software.amazon.awssdk.awscore
software.amazon.awssdk.regions
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs
```

When I am trying to create an eclipse plugin with these packages and install in manually at Felix Console, I am seeing some other packages starts showing unresolved and it goes on an on.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

@alexander-berndt , could you please help me here ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you requiring those dependencies? If not, simply exclude them from the build configuration. Something like this should work for you:

```
                <Import-Package>
                    javax.inject;version=0.0.0,
                    !sun.misc;resolution=optional,!javax.persistence,!com.sun.jdi.*,


                    !software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials,!software.amazon.awssdk.awscore,!software.amazon.awssdk.regions!,software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs

                    *
                </Import-Package>
```